# Display different divs using input checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use 3 input checkbox to display 3 different div. I am using this code but the only one working is "Course 1" and I can't figure out why. I guess it is something pretty easy, but I can't see it:

```js
document.getElementById('checkbox1');

checkbox1.onchange = function() {
  if (checkbox1.checked) {
    course1.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    course1.style.display = 'none';

  }
};

document.getElementById('checkbox2');

checkbox2.onchange = function() {
  if (checkbox2.checked) {
    course2.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    course2.style.display = 'none';

  }
};

document.getElementById('checkbox3');

checkbox3.onchange = function() {
  if (checkbox3.checked) {
    course3.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    course3.style.display = 'none';

  }
};
```

```html
<form>
  <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" checked="true"> Course 1
      </label>
</form>

<form>
  <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" checked="true"> Course 2
      </label>
</form>

<form>
  <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" checked="true"> Course 3
      </label>
</form>

<br>
<div id="course1"> Text course 1
</div>
<br>
<div id="course2"> Text course 2
</div>
<br>
<div id="course2"> Text course 3
</div>
```

Example: https://codepen.io/antonioagar1/pen/dqGaoO

Comment: In your HTML you have `id="course2"` twice.

Comment: You're also not doing anything useful with `document.getElementById()` there since you're discarding its return value. The only reason the code works at all is because - for ancient legacy backwards compatibility reasons - element IDs become properties of the global `window` object.

Comment: OMG, ridiculous. Thanks so much!

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol What would you sugget instead of `document.getElementById()`?

Comment: How about actually *using* `document.getElementById()`? `var cb1 = document.getElementById('checkbox1'); cb1.onchange = {...}`

Comment: I am starting to learn JS as you can see, but I will give it a try and hopefully I will figure out how to use your suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple code instead of your own code:

```
 document.addEventListener("change", function(ev){
    if(ev.target.id.substr(0,8)=="checkbox") document.querySelector("[id='course"+ev.target.getAttribute("id").slice(-1)+"']").style.display=ev.target.checked?"block":"none";
 });
```

- you have two `div` with id `course2`. first, change it to `course3` and then try.

[Check result online](https://jsfiddle.net/k8px0j7v/18/)